# Pytorch Batchnorm layer different from Keras Batchnorm

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, pytorch, batch-normalization

I'm trying to copy pre-trained BN weights from a pytorch model to its equivalent Keras model but I keep getting different outputs.

I read Keras and Pytorch BN documentation and I think that the difference lies in the way they calculate the "mean" and "var".

Pytorch:

> The mean and standard-deviation are calculated per-dimension over the
>   mini-batches

source: [Pytorch BatchNorm](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.BatchNorm2d)

Thus, they average over samples.

Keras:

> axis: Integer, the axis that should be normalized (typically the
>   features axis). For instance, after a Conv2D layer with 
>   data_format="channels_first", set axis=1 in BatchNormalization.

source: [Keras BatchNorm](https://keras.io/layers/normalization/)

and here they average over the features (channels)

What's the right way? How to transfer BN weights between the models?

Comment: Well, you can average all PyTorch means to get an equivalent to the Keras value. For standard deviation it's not that easy (average of standard deviations is not necessarily equal to standard deviation of all channels), but the naive approach may be good enough. Does that work for you?

Comment: I reshaped Keras activations to (BCHW) from (BHWC) and it worked

Comment: Could you post how you solved with a small code snippet? You did not transpose the tensor but swapped axis right?

Answer (score 0):

you can retrieve `moving_mean` and `moving_variance` from `running_mean` and `running_var` attributes of pytorch module

```
# torch weights, bias, running_mean, running_var corresponds to keras gamma, beta, moving mean, moving average

weights = torch_module.weight.numpy()  
bias = torch_module.bias.numpy()  
running_mean =  torch_module.running_mean.numpy()
running_var =  torch_module.running_var.numpy()

keras_module.set_weights([weights, bias, running_mean, running_var])
```